# Makefile trick to get dependencies of a rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there any trick in GNU Makefiles to get all dependencies of a rule?

Example:

```
rule1:  dep1_1 dep1_2 dep1_3

rule2:  dep2_1 dep2_2 rule1

dump_deps:
    echo "Dependencies of rule1: $(call do_the_trick, $(rule1))"
    echo "Dependencies of rule2: $(call do_the_trick, $(rule2))"

install:   $(prefix install-,$(call do_the_trick, $(rule1)))
```

I'd like to be able to call `make dump_deps` and see:

```
dep1_1 dep1_2 dep1_3
dep2_1 dep2_2 dep1_1 dep1_2 dep1_3
```

Or automatically install dependencies with `make install` and things like.

Is it possible?

---

EDIT:

I changed the example to show better that I want something automatic, and not having to hardcode dependency lists myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't show the *transitive* dependencies, only the direct ones, however, you *can* take the output generated below and feed it into the programs [`dot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) (part of  [`graphviz`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)) to make sense of the these transitive relationships.

**Edit:** I guess you could also post-process the results in other ways to just list the deps, but I think pretty pictures are better; feel free to downvote if you disagree ;)

Here's a sample makefile (watch for missing tabs when c&p!):

```
# Makefile that demonstrates how to dump dependencies.
# The macros we use for compiling stuff.
CC_OBJ=$(CC) -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS) $<
CC_BIN=$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^

# If we get "DUMP_DEPS=1 DUMP_DOT=1" on the command line, then instead of
# make-style dependencies, we'll output 'dot' syntax.
# Note: normally, DUMP_DOT_TAIL is undefined, so it doesn't generate any noise.
ifeq ($(DUMP_DOT),1)
DUMP_DOT_HEAD=digraph dependencies {
DUMP_DOT_TAIL=@echo "}"
$(info $(DUMP_DOT_HEAD))
list_dep=@for f in $^; do echo "    \"$@\" -> \"$$f\";"; done
else 
list_dep=@echo "$@: $^"
endif

# If we get "DUMP_DEPS=1" on the command line, then
# instead of building the code, just print the dependencies.
ifeq ($(DUMP_DEPS),1)
CC_OBJ=$(list_dep)
CC_BIN=$(list_dep)
endif

# An implicit rule that builds *.c -> *.o.
%.o:%.c
    $(CC_OBJ)

# Variables for stuff we wanna build.
target=hello

objects=main.o
objects+=stuff.o
objects+=yeah.o

# The top-level 'all' target.
.PHONY: all
all: $(target)
    $(DUMP_DOT_TAIL)

# Builds our final executable
$(target): $(objects)
    $(CC_BIN)

# A standard clean target.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f $(target) $(objects)
```

Now, you can do this:

```
make -B DUMP_DEPS=1
```

And it will go through and list all your pre-requisites is make style of "target: pre-requisite". Sample outputs:

Normal run:

```
cc -o main.o -c  main.c
cc -o stuff.o -c  stuff.c
cc -o yeah.o -c  yeah.c
cc -o hello  main.o stuff.o yeah.o
```

With `make -B DUMP_DEPS=1`:

```
main.o: main.c
stuff.o: stuff.c
yeah.o: yeah.c
hello: main.o stuff.o yeah.o
```

With `make -B DUMP_DEPS=1 DUMP_DOT=1`:

```
digraph dependencies {
    "main.o" -> "main.c";
    "stuff.o" -> "stuff.c";
    "yeah.o" -> "yeah.c";
    "hello" -> "main.o";
    "hello" -> "stuff.o";
    "hello" -> "yeah.o";
}
```

You could then run the following to output a pretty picture to an SVG image:

```
make -B DUMP_DEPS=1 DUMP_DOT=1 | dot -Tsvg > deps.svg
```

Here's what it looks like (this is actually a png, generated with `-Tpng > deps.png`):

[image]

I think this would need some extra work to produce accurate results in all situations, but the principle is sound (e.g. if you use gcc-generated dependency files, you'll need to create them first).

Answer (score 1):

This should list all of the dependencies:

```
DEPEND = dep1 dep2 dep3

.PHONY: $(DEPEND)

dump_deps: $(DEPEND)
     @printf "%s\n" $^
```

You should remove the line with .PHONY target for your needs.  It is used for the sake of the example.  And please note that there is a tab between the beginning of the line and printf.

Comment: In your example I am putting dependencies in `dump_deps` itself, and not in any arbitrary rule I may want to dump. It is not what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the buit in variables available with the make utility , $^ -- this represents all the dependencies of the rule.

also looking thru your code , i did make the rule1 into a variable / macro form to suit my purpose ......

```
rule1 := dep1 dep2 dep3
```

Comment: It is only accessible when the rule is being run. I cannot see dependencies outside of it (wouldn't work if I am trying to list dependent packages to install, as in my example).